# Using Turboreg plugin for imagej

Tags: java, imagej

To install [Turboreg](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/thevenaz/turboreg/) I downloaded the [Unix distibution](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/thevenaz/turboreg/turboreg.tar) (for my Ubuntu machine) and copied the extracted folder Turboreg to the ImageJ/plugins folder. Then opened ImageJ, opened an image, used image/Type/RGB stack to convert 2 images of same size to stack image and went to plugins/TurboReg/TurboReg and clicked on the menu and every time I do that with various images I get the following exception in the

```
ImageJ 1.49p; Java 1.7.0_75 [64-bit]; Linux 3.13.0-46-generic; 3700K of 455MB (<1%)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:56)
    at java.awt.AWTEvent.<init>(AWTEvent.java:337)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.<init>(InvocationEvent.java:285)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.<init>(InvocationEvent.java:174)
    at sun.awt.X11.XBaseMenuWindow.dispose(XBaseMenuWindow.java:907)
    at java.awt.MenuComponent.removeNotify(MenuComponent.java:310)
    at java.awt.Menu.removeNotify(Menu.java:198)
    at java.awt.Component.removeNotify(Component.java:6991)
    at java.awt.Container.remove(Container.java:1199)
    at java.awt.Container.remove(Container.java:1257)
    at turboRegPointToolbar.<init>(TurboReg_.java:5645)
    at turboRegDialog.<init>(TurboReg_.java:1550)
    at TurboReg_.run(TurboReg_.java:314)
    at ij.IJ.runUserPlugIn(IJ.java:199)
    at ij.IJ.runPlugIn(IJ.java:163)
    at ij.Executer.runCommand(Executer.java:131)
    at ij.Executer.run(Executer.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I copied the source code to plugins folder did plugins/compile and run. I used the [PC distribution](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/thevenaz/turboreg/turboreg.zip). Everything I do brings the above exception--I have no idea what I do wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered switching from ImageJ to Fiji (Fiji is just ImageJ, https://fiji.sc/)?

In Fiji you can simply add the BIG-EPFL update site via 'Manage update sites' (see screenshot below) and TurboReg (as well as StackReg) will be automatically installed in Plugins -> Registration.

[image]

This worked out of the box on an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS system for me.